# Why are those the Borel sets?

Tags: measure-theory, rectangles, borel-sets, borel-measures

I have read several definitions and examples, but I still don't understand the Borel-sets clearly.
I found the following: Let $(X,\mathcal{T})$ a topological space. We say $\sigma(\mathcal{T})$ generated $\sigma$-algebra is the Borel-sets of $X$, and we denote it as: $\mathcal{B}(X)$.

First, I don't understand how should I know what is the $\mathcal{T}$ , when I read  $\mathcal{B}(X)$ somewhere?

Second, I don't understand for example in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ how can the $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})=\sigma([a_{i},b_{i}):a_{i}\leq b_{i} , 
i=1,2,...n)$  be the Borel sets? If I have a disk somewhere in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$, how can it be generated by rectangels? Or a disk is not a Borel set? If its not a Borel set, then why?

Another definition is the following (from wikipedia): In mathematics, a Borel set is any set in a topological space that can be formed from open sets (or, equivalently, from closed sets) through the operations of countable union, countable intersection, and relative complement.

In this case, why can't I form a disk through the operations of countable union, countable intersection, and relative complement? If I use other disks it wouldn't be a problem at all.

I know I'm looking forward the smallest $\sigma$-algebra which contains $\mathcal{T}$, but how do I know what is $\mathcal{T}$ for example in the case of $\mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}^{n})$? If they say $\mathcal{T}$ is the set of rectangels in $\mathbb{R}^{2}$ then it would be all clear. However they not mention it. How should I know it if they don't mention such things!?

I hope I was clear. I don't want to write nonsenses, so sorry for that if I did. I just want to clarify  this question once and for all. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Yes, the topology $\tau$ on $\mathbb{R}^n$ is usually the Euclidean topology (unless stated otherwise), The rectangles are not open sets. However, the half-open intervals generate the same $\sigma$-algebra as the open sets and are usually an easier generator to wok with. Also, you *can* form a disk out of half-open intervals using these operations, though an explicit description of how to do so would be rather tedious.

Comment: For instance, you have that $$\prod_{i=1}^n (a_i,b_i)=\bigcup\left\{\prod_{i=1}^n [q_i,b_i)\,:\, \forall i, q_i\in \Bbb Q\cap (a_i,b_i)\right\}$$ The "cubic" open balls are therefore in the generated topology. They form a basis for the euclidean topology, which is second countable: thus all open sets are countable unions of such "balls".

Comment: Because you have *countable* unions you can make disks from rectangles. It's a limiting process..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re: your first question, often - and annoyingly - the topology is omitted so we speak of $\mathcal{B}(X)$ when we should be talking about $\mathcal{B}(X,\mathcal{T})$. In general though this is only done when there is a "natural" choice of topology involved - e.g. if $X=\mathbb{R}^n$, then we're using the Euclidean topology - and so this abuse of notation has survived.

---

As to your second question, as Henno says you *can* form discs via countable unions. Here's a construction which is reasonably simple and will help build intuition:

*This isn't exactly what you ask, but I think it's a bit easier, and understanding it first will make the instance you're looking at much more intuitive.*

> The open unit disc centered at the origin, $U$, is the union of countably many closed rectangles.

(Here we're working in $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the usual topology.)

*Proof:* the initial idea is to put a small closed rectangle $R_p$ around each point $p$ in $U$. Of course that would lead to *uncountably* many closed rectangles, so we combine this with the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2$ has a countable dense set - namely, the set $\mathbb{Q}^2$ of points both of whose coordinates are rational. Of course, this means that it is nontrivial to show that $U$ is in fact covered ...

Specifically, we do the following:

- For $(a,b)\in\mathbb{Q}^2\cap U$, let $\epsilon={\sqrt{a^2+b^2}\over 3}$. Note that the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $(a,b)$ is wholly contained in $U$ and contains $(a,b)$ as an element.
- We now draw a square: let $R_{(a,b)}$ be the closed square centered at $(a,b)$ of side length $\epsilon\sqrt{2}$. This is contained wholly inside the open ball of radius $\epsilon$ centered at $(a,b)$.
- Finally, we claim that $$U=\bigcup_{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Q}^2}R_{(a,b)}.$$ One inclusion is trivial. In the other direction, we want to show that an arbitrary point $(x,y)\in U$ is in $\bigcup_{(a,b)\in\mathbb{Q}^2}R_{(a,b)}$. If $(x,y)\in\mathbb{Q}^2$ this is of course obvious, but what if it's not?
- The solution to this problem is to find a rational point $(a,b)\in U\cap\mathbb{Q}^2$ which is "sufficiently close" to $(x,y)$. This winds up being a bit of annoying "epsilon-juggling" ... so I'm going to leave it as an exercise because I'm lazy and suffering builds character.

---

The real takeaway from the construction in the previous section is that the collection of sets we can build from closed sets via countable intersections *(these are variously called $F_\sigma$ sets or $\Sigma^0_2$ sets - I'll use the former notation since it's more common in topology, even though there's a very good reason to prefer the latter)* is richer than just the collection of closed sets themselves. In particular, a quick extension of the above argument is that every *open* set is $F_\sigma$. Even more simply, the set $\mathbb{Q}^2$ itself is $F_\sigma$ since it's countable, and $\mathbb{Q}^2$ is neither open nor closed.

And of course, this is only (half of) the *second* "layer" of the [Borel hierarchy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borel_hierarchy). Practically *any* set you can describe is Borel.

> On that note, the Borel hierarchy as a more "constructive" description of the collection of Borel sets is extremely useful for building intuition as well as proving theorems.